# Get most unique text from a group of text

Tags: algorithm, similarity

I have a number of texts, for example 100.

I would keep the 10 most unique among them. I made a 100x100 matrix where I compared each text among them with the Levenshtein algorithm.

Is there an algorithm to select the 10 most unique?

EDIT :

What i want is the N most unique text that maximize the distance between this N text regardless of the 1st element of my set.

I want the most unique because i will publish these text to the web and i want avoid near duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

A long comment rather than an answer ...

I don't think you've specified your requirement(s) clearly enough.  How do you select the 1st element of your set of 10 strings ?  Is it the string with the largest distance from any other string (in which case you are looking for the largest element in your array) or the one with the largest distance from all the other strings (in which case you are looking for the largest row- or column-sum in the array).

Moving on to the N (or 10 as you suggest) most distant strings, you have a number of choices.

You could select the N largest distances in the array. I suspect, not having seen your data, that it is likely that the string which is furthest from any other string may also be furthest away from several other strings too -- I mean you may find that several of the N largest entries in your array occur in the same row or column.

You could simply select the N strings with the largest row sums.

Or perhaps you are looking for a cluster of N strings which maximises the distance between all the strings in that cluster and all the strings in the remaining 100-N strings.  This might lead you towards looking at, rather obviously, clustering algorithms.

I suggest you clarify your requirements and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like an eigenvalue problem, I would try to execute the [Power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) on the matrix, and reject the 90 highest values from the resulting vector. The power iteration normally converges very fast, within ~ten iterations. BTW: this solution assumes a similarity matrix. If the entries of your matrix are a measure of **dis**similarity ("distance"), you might need to use their inverses instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the power iteration don't give me the most unique

Comment: If you consider the collection of your texts as a graph/network, the most interconnected/interrelated texts will be at the center of the cluster, and the unrelated ones will be at the outside. But maybe you use a different definition of "the most unique". (for me it is "(the most) different from the rest").

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify what i mean by "most unique". Thanks for the help